# Is it possible to combine these two .htaccess files?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, url-rewriting

I have to completely replace an existing website.  The current site is completely spagetti code with some rewrite rules to mimic friendly urls.

There are some mission critical issues that can't be resolved with the current architecture and database structure, so for a time both code bases need to live side by side.

This is the current .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?q=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?q=$2&r=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?q=$2&r=$3&s=$4
```

I'm replacing it with a zend framework site, but it routes everything through the index.php file for the routing

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can combine the two until the original can be completely replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can map your old URLs to Zend Url someway, then it would be rather easy. Let's say you had

```
http://foo.bar.com/something.php?q=arg1&r=arg2
```

then if you have this functionality working in Zend code, then you must also have valid URL there, like

```
http://foo.bar.com/something/q/arg1/r/arg2
```

If so, all you need is to rewrite that old URLs to Zend URL and instead of doing internal redirection, do HTTP redirection, i.e. (out of my head, not tested):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)&r=(.*)^  
RewriteRule ^something\.php$ /something/q/%1/r/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Mind the trailing "?" which tells mod_rewrite NOT to attach original query string to rewritten one (otherwise you would end with `/something/q/%1/r/%2?q=X&r=y`. Note we do regular 301 HTTP redirection here.

Comment: Well initially only some pages will be routed through the Zend Framework, just the things that have to be fixed now.  So I would say 95% of the site needs to be the original, while only 5% at first will be part of the zend framework.

Comment: Your original rewrite rules are to generic to make that happen. You cannot "catch all" in your rules as Zend is also doing that. Depending on how many links you got you may have to write your rewrite rules more explicitely (if there's a pattern or limited number of targets, then you can even write small script to generate the rules)

Comment: What about if I routed everything through zend, and if I don't find a route tell it to look for the old file using php and note .htaccess rules?

Comment: This would require you to write your own `ErrorController` which would take care of that. Evaluate what is better for you

Comment: I think in the end it would be easiest to route everything through the zend framework.  I already have an ErrorController in place that I can replace the 404 section.  Do you know how I would convert the first rewrite rules to php?

Comment: Use `$_SERVER` global array to get request params. Do `var_dump($_SERVER)` to peek what you got there. Then it would be rather easy task, like splitting/exploding strings, doing some `urldecode()`, and finally redirecting to zend controller of your choice

Comment: I think I see what it's doing. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

They're not going to merge very easily, it's a matter of which one you want to have precedence. You could add a few more conditions to make sure everything doesn't get routed as a `$1.php` file, then add the zend rules to the end.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]+)/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?q=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]+)/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?q=$2&r=$3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^/]+)/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?q=$2&r=$3&s=$4

# other rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: I think for the long term it would be better to route everything through Zend and in my ErrorController reroute any 404 errors.  Can you help me convert the first set of conversion rules to php?  I don't understand it well enough.